# How to fix a slide position using Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to make a slider based on Slick Slider plugin (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

The main point is that I have to fix a position of a slide on click. For example, if I click on slide 3, it will be stucked on its position and every other slide will go through it in an order.

For instance: if slide 3 is clicked, it turns yellow, it is on the third position. We click "Next", the 3rd slide stay fixed, but all the others have moved one position, i.e. visible order of numbers: 2 4 3 5 6... Thus, it always stands motionless "in its place", regardless of the slider paging. The fixation is removed by a second click, the slide remains in the same place and moves with everyone.

I have only the solution when the slide changes its place but I have to do the logic described above. Here's the code I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/tomavl/4mgLrs5t/10/

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
  <div class="slide">6</div>
  <div class="slide">7</div>
  <div class="slide">8</div>
  <div class="slide">9</div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.slider {
  color: #333;
  padding: 0 0 30px;
}

.slide {
  font-size: 90px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.slide.locked { 
  background: rgba(255,255,0,0.5); 
}

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
.slick-next { left:80px; }
```

```
let currentFocus, nextFocus, prevFocus;

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
     responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
        }
      }
    ]
  });

    function setForFocus() {
      nextFocus = currentFocus.next();
    prevFocus = currentFocus.prev();
    if (prevFocus.length == 0)
            prevFocus = null; 
    if (nextFocus.length == 0)
            nextFocus = null; 
  }

  $('.slide').on('click', function() {   
    if ($(this).hasClass('locked')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('locked');
        currentFocus = nextFocus = prevFocus = null;
    } else {
        if (typeof currentFocus !== "undefined" &&
        currentFocus !== null)
            currentFocus.toggleClass('locked');
        $(this).toggleClass('locked');
        currentFocus = $(this);
        setForFocus();      
    }
    
  });

    $('.slick-next').on('click', function() {
    if (typeof currentFocus !== "undefined" &&
        currentFocus !== null && 
      typeof nextFocus !== "undefined" &&   
      nextFocus !== null) {
          let next_text = Number(nextFocus.text());
          let cur_text = Number(currentFocus.text());
              currentFocus.text(next_text);
          nextFocus.text(cur_text);
          currentFocus.toggleClass('locked');
          nextFocus.toggleClass('locked');
          currentFocus = nextFocus;
          setForFocus();  
      }
  });

    $('.slick-prev').on('click', function() {
    if (typeof currentFocus !== "undefined" &&
        currentFocus !== null && 
      typeof prevFocus !== "undefined" &&   
      prevFocus !== null) {
          let prev_text = Number(prevFocus.text());
          let cur_text = Number(currentFocus.text());
              currentFocus.text(prev_text);
          prevFocus.text(cur_text);
          currentFocus.toggleClass('locked');
          prevFocus.toggleClass('locked');
          currentFocus = prevFocus;
          setForFocus();  
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```js
let currentFocus;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.slider').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    $('.slide').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('locked');
        $('.slide').not(this).removeClass('locked')
        currentFocus = $(this);
    });

    $('.slick-next').on('click', function () {
        let next = $(currentFocus).next()
        if (next.length > 0) {
            $('.slide').removeClass('locked')
            next.toggleClass('locked')
            currentFocus = next
        }

    });

    $('.slick-prev').on('click', function () {
        let prev = $(currentFocus).prev()
        if (prev.length > 0) {
            $('.slide').removeClass('locked')
            prev.toggleClass('locked')
            currentFocus = prev
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
        background: #FFF;
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: Helvetica;
    }

    .slider {
        color: #333;
        padding: 0 0 30px;
    }

    .slide {
        font-size: 90px;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }

    .slide.locked {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .slick-prev, .slick-next {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .slick-next {
        left: 80px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">1</div>
    <div class="slide">2</div>
    <div class="slide">3</div>
    <div class="slide">4</div>
    <div class="slide">5</div>
    <div class="slide">6</div>
    <div class="slide">7</div>
    <div class="slide">8</div>
    <div class="slide">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it doesn't work. I tried to change my code in jsfiddle and here in the code snippet here the result is the same. It just selects the slide, but the position doesn't change